# How do I get the MIN() of two fields in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, min

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
name | score_a | score_b
-----+---------+--------
 Joe |   100   |   24
 Sam |    96   |  438
 Bob |    76   |  101
 ... |   ...   |  ...
```

I'd like to select the minimum of score_a and score_b. In other words, something like:

```
SELECT name, MIN(score_a, score_b)
FROM table
```

The results, of course, would be:

```
name | min
-----+-----
 Joe |  24
 Sam |  96
 Bob |  76
 ... | ...
```

However, when I try this in Postgres, I get, "No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts." MAX() and MIN() appear to work across *rows* rather than *columns.*

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 405, accepted):

[LEAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)(a, b):

> The `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions select the largest or smallest value from a list of any number of expressions. The expressions must all be convertible to a common data type, which will be the type of the result (see [Section 10.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html) for details). NULL values in the list are ignored. The result will be NULL only if all the expressions evaluate to NULL.
>
> Note that `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are not in the SQL standard, but are a common extension. Some other databases make them return NULL if any argument is NULL, rather than only when all are NULL...

Comment: For people like me who will also need `MAX()` of two values, it's `GREATEST(a, b)` :)

Comment: @vektor: nice way to add additional search words so that this answer can be found via Google!

Answer (score 36):

Here's the link to docs for the `LEAST()` function in PostgreSQL:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN15582

Answer (score -26):

You can get the answer by putting that data into a column like this:

```
SELECT name, MIN(score_a, score_b) as minimum_score
FROM table
```

Here, we are putting the minimum value among `score_a` and `score_b` and printing the same by storing that value in a column named `minimum_score`.

Comment: only `min(expression)` is existing.

Definition from the doc:
_minimum value of expression across all input values with` expression` is any numeric, string, date/time, network, or enum type, or arrays of these types_